# How to Collect Keyword and Search Engine Data on Webforms?

Tags: forms, seo, cookies

We have a contact form using Contact Form 7 on our wordpress site. We would like to be able to attach any information about where the user came from: keyword search is the #1 item of interest.

We also do a lot of PPC and it would be nice to capture any Ad Group/Campaign information from there as well.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the paid version of the [InfoGeniuz WP plugin for Contact Form 7](http://bit.ly/w3wGSj).

I'm just starting out with it myself, but my initial tests seem very promising. They also have versions for CForms II and Gravity Forms, integrations with Aweber and SalesNexus, and more coming.

Just make sure to back up your WP in general, and contact form settings in particular, before activating. I think there's a bug in this version that reset the content of my Contact Form 7 e-mails to their default settings at install, and it took me all of four minutes to write the e-mail again. ;-) That's a small price to pay for what this plugin provides, though. And it will probably fixed quickly, anayway.

Answer (score 1):

Yoast created a sub-plugin for Gravity to do just what you need. Find the link to the plugin in the yellow note box on this page: http://yoast.com/wordpress/enhanced-wordpress-contact-form/